# Dependency injection - am I missing something?

Tags: model-view-controller, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am using structuremap in an asp.net (mvc) project and I am fairly happy with the functionality. One thing just came to me where I am not sure if I am too blind to see.
I get several services instantiated in my controller class by structure map, but I want them to share methods that are base (hint) to all services. How can I achieve this? Using a base class does not really work (or do I have to reflect on the type?) because the base class methods will not be available in the interface description that defines the service. Do I have to add the method signature into every interface? I want to have all Service classes return their availability (e.g. bool upandrunning).

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces can extend other interfaces in .Net right? In Java it would be:

```
interface BaseService {
    boolean upAndRunning();
}

interface OtherService extends BaseService { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

noah that is it! I knew I was blind outch

```
interface BaseService{  
   bool upAndRunning();
}

interface OtherService : BaseService { ... }
```

is the C# syntax.

Thanks!

Comment: Please don't add answers like this but rather add a comment to noah's answer.